# google mock : error: ‘class ISInfo’ has no member named ‘gmock_registerCallBack’

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have an interface in C++ called SInfo

```
class ISInfo
{
public:
    /// Register a callback
    virtual Handle registerCallBack( const std::string topic) = 0;

    /// De-register a callback
    virtual bool deregisterCallback(Handle handle) = 0;

    /// Deconstructor
    virtual ~ISInfo()
    {
    };
};
```

I have class MSInfo that implements ISInfo

```
class MSInfo : public ISInfo
{
public:
    /// Constructor
    MSInfo( Node *Node);

    /// Deconstructor
    ~MSInfo();

    /// Register a callback
    Handle registerCallBack( const std::string topic);

    /// Deregister
    bool deregisterCallback(Handle handle);
};
```

I have created a Mock class called MockMSInfo as shown below.

```
class MockMSInfo : public MSInfo
{
public:
    MockMSInfo(Node *node) : MSInfo(ode) {}
    MOCK_METHOD1(registerCallBack, Handle(const std::string topic));
    MOCK_METHOD1(deregisterCallback, bool(Handle topicHandle));
};
```

In my unit test,I create a Mock object of the above type `MockMSInfo` as below

```
Node *node = new Node();
ISInfo *isInfo = new MockMSInfo(node);
```

The problem is when I do

```
EXPECT_CALL(*isInfo, registerCallBack(_));
```

I get the below error

```
googletest/install/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:2026:16: error: ‘class ISInfo’ has no member named ‘gmock_registerCallBack’
   ((mock_expr).gmock_##call)(::testing::internal::GetWithoutMatchers(), \
                ^
googletest/install/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:2034:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘GMOCK_ON_CALL_IMPL_’
   GMOCK_ON_CALL_IMPL_(obj, InternalExpectedAt, call)
   ^
MonitorUnitTests.cpp:52:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘EXPECT_CALL’
     EXPECT_CALL(*isInfo, registerCallBack(_));
```

Comment: Seems there is a closing parenthesis missing in `MOCK_METHOD1(registerCallBack, Handle(const std::string topic);`

Comment: @heapunderrun - I fixed that. But that certainly isn't the problem. That was missed somehow posting here. My actual code is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a starter: I propose you derive from the base class, not from the impl class:

```
class MockMSInfo : public ISInfo
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(registerCallBack, Handle(const std::string topic));
    MOCK_METHOD1(deregisterCallback, bool(Handle topicHandle));
};
```

And now the actual problem: the compiler is your friend here. Indeed, you want to call a method that is not available in `IsInfo`. See, you've created an instance of `MockMSInfo`, but you've assigned it to a ptr to the base class (i.e. `ISInfo *`). The macro `MOCK_METHOD*` adds a new method to the *mock* class (but of course, not the base class!), called `gmock_<METHOD_NAME>`. And `EXPECT_CALL` requires such method to be defined in the class passed. But you passed `ISInfo *`. Therefore, to fix this, just create the mock and use `MockMSInfo *` as the type. Working example https://godbolt.org/z/Pe8eM9E9s.